# What is the difference between electrostatic and electric potential energy?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, potential-energy, terminology, definition

In circuits what is the difference between electrostatic and electric potential energy?

Side question does electrostatic potential energy even exist in a circuit?

Comment: This may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318697/

Comment: I think you are mixing *electric potential* and *electrostatic potential energy*, which are two terms applied to somewhat different aspects of the same situation.